# Criando uma Exception personalizada a partir de PDOException

Tags: php, try-catch, pdoexception

Olá.

Preciso implementar uma Exception personalizada que estende de PDOException e com isso criar alguns métodos que retorne mensagens padrões. Até agora só encontrei exemplos pouco claros. Alguém tem algum exemplo simples?

Comment: Boa tarde Raphael, desculpe, não está claro, você quer entender o como funciona a implementação em uma `Exception` existente, ou você quer entender como funciona os `Exceptions`? Edite a pergunta pra deixar mais evidente a sua necessidade. Tenho certeza que vai levar o comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um exemplo simples, onde a classe MyPDOException endende a classe PDOException, que assim podendo fazer uma mensagem personalizada quando ocorre um erro utilizando a classe PDO.

```
class MyPDOException extends PDOException { }

class MyClass {
    public function myFunction() {

        try {
            try {

                throw new MyPDOException('Sua mensagem de erro!');
            } catch (MyPDOException $e) {
                throw $e;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
}

$foo = new MyClass;
$foo->myFunction();
```